# How to mark the unfilled fields in Django web page?

Tags: django, django-forms

While filling up the details in web page based on django framework, if user forgets any field, I want to mark that field as in circle it in red that this cannot be submitted as circled field is empty.
Earlier I was simple directing it to Error html page which doesn't tell about what exact error has been made.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each field has an `field.errors` attribute (it's an iterable) that contains the errors for this field. In addition, the form itself has a similar `non_field_errors` attribute containing errors pertaining to no particular field.

The [documentation provides an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template) on how to indicate which fields caused errors.

Alternatively, you could use an helper app such as [django crispy forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms) which integrates with [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).